# What does this error mean: `somefile.c:200: error: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes`?

Tags: c, gcc, build, makefile, compiler-errors

During a make, I'm seeing an error along the lines of:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
somefile.c:200: error: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes
```

The line number points to the closing brace of a c function that has a signature like this:

```
void trace(SomeEnum1 p1, SomeEnum2 p2, char* format, ...) {
    char strBuffer[1024];
    ...
```

The function prints some stuff into the buffer.

Anyone know what this type of error means in general?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm guessing there's some large buffer in that routine that is stack-allocated; this is likely causing the stack frame of that function to exceed 1024 bytes, which seems to be some compiler-enforced limit for the architecture upon which you are building. Possible solutions would include passing a compiler flag to relax the warning, expand the upper limit of the stack size, or dynamically allocating the buffer.

Comment: In fact the first thing that happens is an allocation of a buffer of size 1024.

Comment: Man I was gonna say this too, but I wanted to see the function first. :)

Answer (score 14):

Here is the GCC documentation referring to this warning:

`STACK_CHECK_MAX_FRAME_SIZE`

The maximum size of a stack frame, in bytes. GNU CC will generate probe instructions in non-leaf functions to ensure at least this many bytes of stack are available. If a stack frame is larger than this size, stack checking will not be reliable and GNU CC will issue a warning. The default is chosen so that GNU CC only generates one instruction on most systems. You should normally not change the default value of this macro.

From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_17.html#SEC214

Comment: The stack frame is where the compiler places auto variables. If you have any local variables other then strBuffer you're going to overflow the 1024 limit. Try to reduce the size of strBuffer to make room for additional local variables. The compiler may also use some space in the stack frame for it's own use, typically saving the return address and hardware registers.

Comment: You can also try moving strBuffer from the stack to some other memory area like the heap or global memory. Moving it to the heap would require using malloc and free and you'd take a performance hit. While moving it to global space would only require adding the 'static' qualifier, but you'd loose some global space. I'm making all kinds of assumptions about your hardware and compiler.

Answer (score 13):

**`-Wframe-larger-than`**

The warning is generated by `-Wframe-larger-than`. `man gcc` of GCC 7 says:

> Warn if the size of a function frame is larger than len bytes.  The computation done to determine the stack frame size is approximate and not conservative.  The
>      actual requirements may be somewhat greater than len even if you do not get a warning.  In addition, any space allocated via "alloca", variable-length arrays,
>      or related constructs is not included by the compiler when determining whether or not to issue a warning.

**Minimal example**

main.c

```
int main(void) {
    char s[1024];
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -O0 -Wframe-larger-than=1 main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:1: warning: the frame size of 1040 bytes is larger than 1 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
$ gcc -std=c99 -O0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 main.c
# No warning.
```

**Why this exists**

Operating systems must limit the stack size, otherwise it would grow until it reaches the heap / `mmap`s and everything would break unpredictably.

Linux sends a signal if the program tries to grow beyond that maximum stack size.

`-Wframe-larger-than=` is a way to help to prevent the stack from overflowing, by keeping function local variables (which are placed on the stack) small.

There is no compile time guarantee however, since the problem is likely to happen when calling recursive functions, and it all comes down to how many times it recurses.

The solution is to allocate memory with `malloc` instead of using large arrays as local variables. This ends up using `mmap` memory.

The key difference between the stack and `malloc` memory is that the stack must be contiguous, which is simple leads to great memory packing efficiency, while `malloc` requires complex heuristics. See also:

- [What is the function of the push / pop instructions used on registers in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass/33583134#33583134)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux/239323#239323