# How does sbrk() work?

Tags: c, unix, sbrk, brk

I'm trying to understand how `sbrk` works.

Here is my little code:

```
int  main()
{  
    printf("end of the break : %p\n", sbrk(0));
    printf("end of the break : %p\n", sbrk(10));
    printf("new end of the break : %p\n\n", sbrk(0));
}
```

This outputs:

> ```
> end of break : 0xaa6000    
> end of break : 0xac7000    
> new end of the break : 0xac700a
> ```

Why is the difference between the first 2 addresses
0xac7000 - 0xaa6000 = 21000 and not 10?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does brk( ) system call do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-brk-system-call-do)

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I don't see an answer to this question in your link.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is clearly stated and perfectly reasonable. It's also *not* answered by simply looking at the documentation or wikipedia.

Answer (score 14):

`sbrk(n)` increments the break by `n` and returns the *old* value of the break.

Thus:

```
    printf("end of the break : %p\n", sbrk(0));
```

Output: `end of the break : 0xaa6000`

Initially, the break is 0xaa6000 and the `sbrk` call doesn't change it.

```
    printf("end of the break : %p\n", sbrk(10));
```

Output: `end of the break : 0xac7000`

This is the value you're asking about. Above I said `sbrk(0)` wouldn't change the break, so why do we get a different value here?

The only thing that's happened in between the two `sbrk` call is the call to the first `printf`. Presumably the internals of your stdio implementation use `malloc` (e.g. to create buffers), which in turn calls `sbrk` itself. In other words, `printf` calls `malloc` internally, which reserves memory using `sbrk`.

```
    printf("new end of the break : %p\n\n", sbrk(0));
```

Output: `new end of the break : 0xac700a`

This time we see an increment of 0xa, which matches your previous `sbrk(10)` call exactly. Apparently this time `printf` didn't need to allocate dynamic memory (or if it did, `malloc` was able to do everything within the space it got from the first `sbrk`, so it didn't have to request more from the OS).

Comment: Okey thanks it was just because of printf.
Thanks for your answer !