# What's unsafe/legacy about brk/sbrk?

Tags: c, malloc, legacy, sbrk, brk

I've heard in a lot of places (musl mailing list, macOS forums, etc.) that `brk()` and `sbrk()` are unsafe. Many of these places either don't give explanations at all, or give very vague explanations. For example, [this](https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2013/12/21/1) link states that "these functions are fundamentally broken", and goes on to say that the `malloc` and `sbrk` subsystems are utterly broken, that they ruin the heap, et al.

My question is: Why is this so? If `malloc` is used in such a way that it allocates a block of memory with `sbrk` large enough to quell or substantially decrease the need for further allocations, then shouldn't `sbrk` and `brk` be perfectly safe to use?

Here are my implementations of `sbrk` and `brk`:

`sbrk`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void *sbrk(intptr_t inc)
{
        intptr_t curbrk = syscall(SYS_brk, NULL);

        if( inc == 0 ) goto ret;

        if( curbrk < 0 ) return (void *)-1;

        curbrk((void *)(curbrk+inc));
ret:
        return (void *)curbrk;
}
```

`brk`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

intptr_t brk(void *ptr)
{
        if( (void *)syscall(SYS_brk, ptr) != ptr )
                return -1;
        else
                return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is explenation right there in the text `For an application to use them
correctly, it must depend on the malloc subsystem never being used,
but this is impossible to guarantee since malloc may be used
internally by libc functions without documenting this to the
application.`. If your app calls sbrk and your app calls malloc and malloc calls sbrk and sbrk function uses global context, the result will be a mess. They want to eliminate the sbrk function, to make users not use it, not because it is a bad design per se.

Comment: What does "global context" mean? A quick Google search doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: `sbrk` usually operates on a single global variable, ex `__curbrk` in [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/sbrk.c) or `static char *heap_end;` in [newlib](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/libgloss/epiphany/sbrk.c). That means that all "contexts" (threads, functions, malloc, printf and user app) share the same ("global" to the process) data segment.

Comment: That's odd, my implementation just uses the return code from `syscall(SYS_brk, 0)`.

Comment: My guess is that certain `malloc` implementations are written to assume that nobody else is calling `sbrk` behind their back.  For instance, suppose you call `p = malloc(N)` where N is some large number (maybe a multiple of page size).  malloc does `sbrk(N)` to get memory from the OS and returns this pointer to you.  Later (without any intervening calls to malloc) you do `free(p)`.  Now malloc "knows" that it can do `sbrk(-N)` to return the memory to the OS.  If you have called `sbrk` in between, then you have a problem.

Comment: Of an alternative which would be a lot safer is to `sbrk` a multiple of `N` and then implement a `free(...)` which only marks the memory as available for other uses. You really have a lot of control when you write a standard C library from scratch :).

Comment: That would alleviate the possibility of an `sbrk` screwing anything up, because `malloc`'s memory has already been allocated.

Comment: Then, of course, at the end of program execution all `free`d memory could be cleaned up and deallocated.

Comment: [awkwardly written, but good basic malloc introduction](https://github.com/zyfjeff/C-HOW-TO/blob/master/c-malloc/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) for writing your own memory manager with `brk/sbrk` (intro level only)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reality highly depends on the implementation but here are some elements:

#### unsafe

`brk`/`sbrk` were invented to allow a process to request more memory from the system, and release it in a single contiguous segment. As such, they were used by many `malloc` and `free` implementations. The problem was that, as it returned a unique segment, things would go wrong as multiple modules (of the same process) use it directly. It became even worse in a multi-threaded process because of race conditions. Suppose 2 threads want to add new memory. They will look at the current top address with `sbrk(0)`, see the same address, request new memory with either `brk` or `sbrk`, and because of the race condition, will both use the same memory.

Even in a single threaded process, some `malloc` and `free` implementations assume that they only are allowed to use the low level `s/brk` interface, and that any other code should use them. In that case things will go wrong if the image of the break segment that they internally maintain is no longer the assumed value. They should have to guess that some parts of the segment are "reserved" for other uses, possibly breaking the ability to release any memory.

For that reason, user code should never directly use `brk`/`sbrk` and only rely on `malloc`/`free`. If, and only if, you are writing an implementation of the standard library including `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc`/`free`, you can safely use `brk`/`sbrk`

#### legacy

On modern system, `mmap` can make a much nicer usage of virtual memory management. You can use as many dynamic memory segments as you need with no interaction between them. So, on a modern system, unless you have a specific need for memory allocation using `brk`/`sbrk`, you should use `mmap`.

#### portability

The FreeBSD reference for `brk` and `sbrk` states this:

> The brk() and sbrk() functions are legacy interfaces from before the
>     advent of modern virtual memory management.

and later:

> BUGS:
>     Mixing brk() or sbrk() with malloc(3), free(3), or similar functions will
>     result in non-portable program behavior.

Comment: That's about as good an explanation I've seen. Don't mix `malloc` with your owns calls to `brk/sbrk`. I think you are right. If `malloc` can't find the break where it left it, then it likely won't release any of the memory it originally allocated. I haven't looked at the `malloc` source, but that makes sense.

Comment: This is definitely a better explanation than I've seen so far. However, it begs the question: If I can make `malloc()` and `free()` check for program break changes, is it possible to safely use `sbrk()` and `brk()` with my C library? I'll also give you a +1 for mentioning threads. I haven't implemented them yet, so I hadn't thought about it. Thanks!