Where Is The Program Break Of A Process Located?
I have recently started reading some documentation on brk() and sbrk(), and I understand that the entire point of these system calls is to modify the program break, which points to the top of the heap segment for a process.
But how does the kernel know where to find the program break value for a process? Can it be found within the process table or does a specific CPU register hold this value?
I looked into Intel's x86-64 and could not find any details on the program break that would suggest to me that its stored in a CPU register. Furthermore, I cannot seem to figure out how I can view the process table.

There is a detailed explanation of brk()/sbrk() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-the-brk-system-call-do

Note that this is a very outdated concept. The observable behavior is kept for backwards compatibility, but the whole notion of "the heap segment" (one) and "the stack"(one) is long gone.

This value is definitely not stored in a register. That would be extremely wasteful. Registers are extremely limited and not used for this kind of rarely-used values.
"The process table" is a shorthand to describe all kinds of data that belong to a process. For instance, "the process table" contains information about all threads of a program, but that obviously isn't a fixed-length array. Many programs have only one thread, others have thousands. Some things are only dynamically allocated when needed.
As brk is entirely outdated (it was removed from POSIX two decades ago), the value might not even exist until an old-fashioned program runs and calls brk or sbrk.
See also What's unsafe/legacy about brk/sbrk?

Thanks for the breakdown! I did not know brk was removed. But I am still curious to know where this value was stored before POSIX removed it.
A further question I would have is, if brk was removed why can we still make the syscall using a program. It still seems like it is working as documented in my test C program.

@flyingdot: Why do you think it's a syscall? I think it's currently a glibc function, not Linux.
