# Will PUSH instruction generate an EXIT

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, virtual-machine

Consider the following sequence of guest VM instructions:

```
701: 55     push %rbp 
702: 41 54  push %r12 
704: 41 55  push %r13
```

For any of the above instruction is an `EXIT` is possible for any reason?
I think YES it is possible because PUSH can raise a page fault if a stack is not present.

Am I correct or wrong?

Comment: Yes. It can raise a page [fault][1]. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass

Comment: @Johan If the page that `RSP - 8` points to isn't present (or isn't writable or is invalid) then the CPU will generate a page fault when executing these instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quoting Intel and thus implicitly referring to the VT-x technology.
AMD-v is similar, though (Particularly, exceptions are still intercepted).

---

Exceptions can cause a VMExit if the VMM (the program running in VMX root mode) has configured the VMCS to allow it:

> **Exceptions.** Exceptions (faults, traps, and aborts) cause VM exits based on the exception bitmap (see Section
>   24.6.3). If an exception occurs, its vector (in the range 0–31) is used to select a bit in the exception bitmap. If
>   the bit is 1, a VM exit occurs; if the bit is 0, the exception is delivered normally through the guest IDT.

So if the sequence of instruction generates any exception, it opens the possibility of a VMExit.

Besides the #PF there are other exceptions that a `push` can generate:

> **#GP(0)** If the memory address is in a non-canonical form.
>   **#SS(0)** If the stack address is in a non-canonical form.
>   **#PF(fault-code)** If a page fault occurs.
>   **#AC(0)** If alignment checking is enabled and an unaligned memory reference is made while the
>   current privilege level is 3.

As [Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895276/will-push-instruction-generate-an-exit/42898443?noredirect=1#comment72899886_42898443) pointed out in the comments, a VMExit can also occur due to an EPT (nested pages in AMD terminology if IIRC) fault.
Also, the #GP is not relevant for the snippet posted.

Comment: #GP can't happen with the given instructions because they don't have a memory operand. The instructions can also cause EPT violation/misconfiguration VM exits, which are basically meta-page-faults.