# Werror=frame-larger-than error

Tags: gcc, stack, frame, stack-overflow

I found what I believe to be a bug in the 4.6.2 compiler.  If I compile with the flag -Werror=frame-larger-than=1024 flag, it generates error:

arch/mips/bcm963xx/irq.c:553:1: error: the frame size of 16 bytes is larger than 1 bytes [-Werror=frame-larger-than=]

If I remove this flag it compiles properly (I should also note that the -Wframe-larger-than=1024 flag is set on the command line before the -Werror=frame-larger-than=1024 flag, but the second flag seems to override the first).

Could someone confirm if this is indeed a bug, or whether I'm missing something?

My compiler version is:
mips-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc (Buildroot 2011.11) 4.6.2

Thanks
John

Comment: I'll assume this is a bug, and report it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this error mean: \`somefile.c:200: error: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450845/what-does-this-error-mean-somefile-c200-error-the-frame-size-of-1032-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, for somoe reason 1024 value is considered as 1023, change ir in your `.config` file

**CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=4096** instead of CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=1024

[Config Frame Warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfOEn.png)

Answer (score 0):

`CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=0` will disable checking.